# How to normalize histogram height to unity?

Tags: plotting, data, histograms

When doing `Histogram[data]`, I get the total number of counts in each bin. Doing `Histogram[data, Automatic, "Probability"]` normalizes the *area* to unity, so typically the height of the histogram will be $<1$. Similarly, `Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]` won't have unit height.

So, how to make a histogram have normalized height?

Comment: The answer below directly answers your question but I'm curious as to why you'd want to do this as this is not a good way to compare different histograms.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I want to emphasize the shape of a histogram, and the height is irrelevant for this. And having one histogram two or five times lower than another makes it not so clear.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  This might cross over the line and be more appropriate for a "chat" but I'd argue that comparing histograms appropriately is on an "equal area" basis rather than an "equal height" basis.  If it is a single histogram then, minimizing the white space with a scale where the tallest bar is at the top of the figure is definitely the way to go.  But not for comparing histograms (or smoothed histograms).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use your own normalization function

```
Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], Automatic, #2/Max@#2 &]
```

[image]